# How to play a wav content with the bitrate of 256kbps by audio_play?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi every one,
we provide a wav content with the bitrate of 16kbps for the audio_play to play, it is ok. Now, if the bitrate is another one, for example 256kbps, what shoud we do? Should we change the bitrate of the wav content? Should some one help me?

thanks

I have do some test like this:

I have put the test source codes to the github, every one can git them from : [test bite rate for audio play](https://github.com/78226415/test_bite_rate_for_audio_play).

My enviroment is: ubuntu 14.04 LTS, ros indigo.

First you should install the audio_common: sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-audio-common

Secondly, open the test_bite_rate_audio_play_server/src/test_bite_rate_audio_play_server.cpp, you will see the two lines codes:

**FILE *fp_test = fopen("/home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/src/test_bite_rate_audio_play_server/res/test2.wav", "r");  // this is no sound, it's bite rate is 256kbps**

**//FILE *fp_test = fopen("/home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/src/test_bite_rate_audio_play_server/res/test1.wav", "r"); // this is ok, the bite rate is 16kbps**

you should replace the file path for your local environment.
Then build the packages.

Third, open a terminal and run : roscore

the next few new tap, you may be run the source: source /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

open a new tap and run: rosrun audio_play audio_play audio:=audio_content_publisher

open a new tap and run: rosrun audio_server audio_content_publish_server

open a new tap and run: rosrun test_bite_rate_audio_play_server test_bite_rate_audio_play_server

Then you should hear nothing, or see a message at the final tap terminal: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Now, do the second test, it is nearly the same as the first test, common the first line and uncommon the second line, like this:

**//FILE *fp_test = fopen("/home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/src/test_bite_rate_audio_play_server/res/test2.wav", "r");  // this is no sound, it's bite rate is 256kbps**

**FILE *fp_test = fopen("/home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/src/test_bite_rate_audio_play_server/res/test1.wav", "r"); // this is ok, the bite rate is 16kbps**

when you run the final command, you will hear some sound.

The different of the two test is : the bite rate of wav files is different, one is 16kbps and the other is 256kbps, so some would help me? thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241080/how-to-play-a-wav-content-with-the-bitrate-of-256kbps-by-audio_play?/) by [78226415](https://answers.ros.org/users/27677/78226415/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-08-09**:
Have you tried playing a 256kbps wav file to see if it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Firstly, audio_play was not designed to be used this way; it's really only designed as an endpoint for data from audio_capture (and it's barely good at that). If you want to play wave files or do text to speech, I suggest you start with [sound_play](http://wiki.ros.org/sound_play) and only move to audio_play if that doesn't work for you.

I was able to reproduce your issue with the instructions you provided; they're very complete!

I found two issues:

The first was that your program segfaults (memory error) when I try to run it. This is a bug in your program and not really related to the bit rate, but it only happened with the 256kbps file because it was a larger file. Your file read code was corrupting memory and crashing your program. You can see more details about this bu running your program with valgrind:

```
rosrun --prefix valgrind test_bite_rate_audio_play_server test_bite_rate_audio_play_server
```

Once I fixed your test program, the second thing I found is that audio_play expects all of the data at the same bit rate, so if you send it data at one bit rate it expects all of the data at that bit rate. This means that playing a 16kbps file and then a 256kbps file doesn't work. It also means that if you play a 256kbps file first, it works fine.

The fixed version of your program is:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "test_bite_rate_audio_play_server");
  ros::NodeHandle _nh;
  ros::ServiceClient audioContentPublishClient = _nh.serviceClient<hlf_common_srv::AudioPublishData>("audio_content_publish_server");

  int total_count = 0;
  const int read_size = 1024;
  int buffer_size = read_size * 64; // initialize the buffer to 64k bytes
  char * audio_buffer = (char*)malloc(buffer_size); // allocate the initial buffer
  //the next two lines, you should replace the file path for your local environment
  FILE *fp_test = fopen("/home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/src/test_bite_rate_audio_play_server/res/test2.wav", "r"); // this is no sound, it's bite rate is 256kbps
  //FILE *fp_test = fopen("/home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/src/test_bite_rate_audio_play_server/res/test1.wav", "r"); // this is ok, the bite rate is 16kbps

  if (fp_test == NULL) {
    ROS_INFO("Open file failed");
    return 1;
  }

  int read_count = fread(audio_buffer, 1, read_size, fp_test);
  total_count = read_count;

  while(read_count == read_size)
  {
    // if there isn't enough space in the buffer for the next read, realloc
    // to increase the buffer size
    if(total_count + read_count > buffer_size) {
      buffer_size *= 2;
      audio_buffer = (char*)realloc(audio_buffer, buffer_size);
    }

    read_count = fread(audio_buffer + total_count, 1, read_size, fp_test);
    total_count += read_count;
  }

  fclose(fp_test);
  //ROS_INFO("wav data : %s \n", tts_receive_data); 
  ROS_INFO("total_count : %d \n", total_count);

  hlf_common_srv::AudioPublishData audio_publish_msg;
  audio_publish_msg.request.audioPlayContent = std::string( audio_buffer, total_count );
  audioContentPublishClient.call(audio_publish_msg);

  ROS_INFO("test server is over.");

  ros::spin();
}
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2